# Select specific columns from a JOIN

Tags: magento2, sql

I am using this class

```
$resource = \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
connection = $resource->getConnection();
```

to get data from some custom tables using a JOIN

```
$select = $block->connection->select()
    ->from(['table1' => $this->getTable('table1')])
    ->join( ['table2' => 'table2'],
        'table1.id = table2.package_group_id')
    ->join(['table3' => 'table3'],
        'table2.isbn = table3.sku')
    ->where('table1.custom_site_url_key =?',$school_key_url);
```

This is returning all the columns but I just want one column from table 1 and another from table 3. Someone know how can I get just the necessary columns?

Thanks

Comment: You can echo $select and debug the query in mysql, then only you will get to know that it has one records or multi-records and also there is an issue with magento select function or your query that you have passed in select function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify needed columns in the second argument of from clause:

```
->from(
    ['table1' => $this->getTable('table1')],
    ['table1.columnA', 'table3.columnB']
)
```